# PyCharm runs a completely different code when i hit "run"

Tags: python, pycharm

I wrote a code to open a CSV file with pandas

```
from pandas import read_csv
print(read_csv("weather_data.csv"))
```

But when I tried to run it in PyCharm, a completely different code that I wrote weeks ago gets executed.

I checked that I execute the right file, and even deleted the project multiple times and created it in different locations.

Another thing that confuses me is when I edit this code to:

```
print("hello")

from random import randint
from pandas import read_csv

print("hello")
print(randint(1,10))
print(read_csv("weather_data (1).csv"))
```

the output is:

```
hello
Pls enter a number: (-> the game i made weeks ago)
```

This code seems to get executed when I import packages, because the print function before works fine.

Comment: You have apparently named your older script either `random.py` or `pandas.py`, so one of your `import` statements is actually finding that script rather than the intended module.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I checked its not the random but the pandas import that opens the file. But lets say i did name a file pandas.py. How and why is it possible that from pandas import read_csv a file is being opened thats in a completely different folder anywhere on my computer? Thank you

Comment: The directories that are searched to find an imported file are listed in `sys.path`.  Obviously the old script is in a directory that's earlier on that list than the one containing installed modules - I'd guess its the very first entry, which is an empty string (meaning to look in the current working directory).  It is entirely intentional that you can override installed modules, so that you can apply patches or add logging to their contents.

Comment: thanks again, so im pretty new and i dont know exactly what to do with this. Can you explain to me how i could solve my problem? really appreciated